# UITapGestureRecognizer Not Working on Xcode 4.1/iOS 4.3

Tags: ios4, uibutton, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, xcode4.1

I'm trying to implement an Expandable Table View Cell, using this example: 
http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/ 
Here, they're using Xcode 4.3, with iOS 5, but I have to implement it using Xcode4.1, with iOS 4.3. Using this version, my view/button doesn't recognize when the button is tapped, but I compiled my project, using the same classes, but with Xcode 4.3/iOS 5, and the tap it is recognized, so the classes are fine. 
Here is the code that creates the UIView with the button: 
SectionView.m

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withTitle:(NSString *)title section:(NSInteger)sectionNumber delegate:(id<SectionView>)Delegate{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(discButtonPressed:)];
        [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        self.section = sectionNumber;
        self.delegate = Delegate;

        CGRect labelFrame = self.bounds;
        labelFrame.size.width -= 50;
        CGRectInset(labelFrame, 0.0, 5.0);

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        label.text = title;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [self addSubview:label];
        self.sectionTitle = label;

        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(labelFrame.size.width, 0, 50, labelFrame.size.height);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = buttonFrame;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(discButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:button];
        self.discButton = button;
    }

    return self;
 }
```

This is the class that creates/delegates from SectionView: 
TableDropViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SectionView.h"

@interface TableDropViewController : UITableViewController <SectionView>

@end
```

And this method creates the object SectionView: 
TableDropViewController.m

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    SectionInfo *si = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
    if(!si.sectionView){
        NSString *title = si.category;
        si.sectionView = [[SectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 45) withTitle:title section:section delegate:self];
    }
    return si.sectionView;
}
```

I'll really appreciate the help. Thanks